# How can I count rows having distinct IP address per day?

Tags: mysql

How can I count how many unique addresses have been on my site each day?
My table looks like this:

> Row names: id, name, entity, ip_address, date
>
> 1,"Baldur","EntityA","85.221.18.251","2012-01-09 17:32:52"
>   2,"Baldur","EntityB","85.221.18.251","2012-01-09 17:32:57"
>   3,"Baldur","EntityB","85.221.18.252","2012-01-09 17:33:01"
>   4,"Baldur","EntityA","85.221.18.253","2012-01-10 17:33:12"
>   5,"Mango","EntityA","85.221.18.257","2012-01-10 17:32:52"
>   6,"Baldur","EntityB","85.221.18.251","2012-01-10 17:32:57"
>   7,"Mango","EntityB","85.221.18.253","2012-01-11 17:33:01"
>   8,"Mango","EntityA","85.221.18.251","2012-01-11 17:33:12"
>   9,"Mango","EntityA","85.221.18.253","2012-01-11 17:32:52"
>   10,"Baldur","EntityB","85.221.18.255","2012-01-11 17:32:57"
>   11,"Mango","EntityB","85.221.18.254","2012-01-11 17:33:01"
>   12,"Mango","EntityA","85.221.18.251","2012-01-12 17:33:12"

I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(ip)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY date
```

This only gives me rows with count of one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not grouping by a date (meaning one entry per day), but on the actual timestamp, which in your case comes down to a second. You have to apply the `date` function to extract the actual date from it.

On the other hand add the `DISTINCT` keyword to actually count different ips and ignore duplicate entries.

```
SELECT DATE( `date` ), COUNT( DISTINCT ip_address )
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY DATE( `date` )
```

Comment: @Steven maybe check for some typos. it runs fine at my local mysql db and returns 4 rows.

Answer (score 2):

You only get counts of 1 because most of your date values are essentially unique, owing to the fact that they have a time component too. So your original statement attempted to group by the full datetime, but you won't typically have many hits per second.

Use the function `DATE()` to strip away the time portion, and get only the date portion, and add `DISTINCT` inside the `COUNT()` to get only the unique IPs per day.

```
SELECT 
  DATE(`date`) AS ipdate, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT ip) 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ipdate
```

To get the total (non-unique) hits per day, omit the `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(`date`) AS ipdate, 
  COUNT(ip) 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ipdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DATE(date), COUNT(ip) FROM mytable GROUP BY DATE(date),ip
```