# MySQL GROUP BY returns one row

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get total no of unique rows on daily ip bases, Repeating ip on another day shall be counted for row.

I also followed these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191021/mysql-count-the-distinct-rows-per-day), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668171/how-can-i-count-rows-having-distinct-ip-address-per-day), approach's but didn't worked

I am doing this way

Database

```
|    ip      |  date    |
| 1698170033 | 19032016 |
| 1698170034 | 19032016 |
| 1698170033 | 19032016 |
| 1698170033 | 20032016 |
| 1698170034 | 20032016 |
| 1698170035 | 20032016 |
| 1698170036 | 20032016 |
| 1698170033 | 20032016 |
```

MySQl

```
SELECT 
`date`, `ip`
FROM `stats`.`stats`    
GROUP BY `date`
```

This gives result as

```
| 1698170033 | 19032016 |
| 1698170033 | 20032016 |
```

Expected result

```
| 1698170033 | 19032016 |
| 1698170033 | 20032016 |
| 1698170034 | 20032016 |
| 1698170035 | 20032016 |
| 1698170036 | 20032016 |
```

Please suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: group by both `ip and date`

Comment: @1000111 thanks that worked.

Comment: You are welcome :) @TallboY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` `ip` field too:

```
SELECT `date`, `ip`
FROM `stats`.`stats`    
GROUP BY `date`, `ip`
```

This will give you a distinct list of all the `date`, `ip` pairs of your table.

Comment: I have one more issue now, please see update in question,there is a column `value` and I need to add these value too I do like SUM(`value`) but it adds all occurance of `value` for a given ip `1698170033` like `2900` for date `20032016 `

Comment: @TallboY Can you try posting a different question as this is a different problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use group by date and ip

```
SELECT `date`, `ip` FROM `stats`.`stats`GROUP BY `date`, `ip`
```

Comment: @Tall boY can you check my query?